# Ajax dropdown selected doesn't work for updating data in Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5.6

I'm using Laravel 5.6. I want to make update data, there is selected dropdown using ajax. I have two database with foreign key. I use ajax too for making selected product in create form, it works. But, when i use it in update form, it doesn't work.

This my code:

web.php

```
Route::resource('admins/order', 'NotifController');
Route::get('admins/order/ajax/{id}', 'NotifController@withAjax');
```

Controller

```
public function edit(Order $order)
{
    $produks    = Produk::pluck('nama_produk', 'id');
    return view('admins/order/edit', compact('order', 'produks'));
}

public function withAjax($id){
    $items = Item::all()
              ->where('id_produk',$id)
              ->pluck('nama_item','id');
    return json_encode($items);
}

public function update($id, Request $request)
{
    $order = Order::findOrFail($id);
    $data = $request->all();

    if($request->hasFile('filebrief')){
      $exist     = Storage::disk('foto')->exists($order->filebrief);
      if(isset($order->filebrief) && $exist) {
        $delete  = Storage::disk('filebrief')->delete($order->filebrief);
      }

      $filebrief = $request->file('filebrief');
      if($request->file('filebrief')->isValid()){
        $file_name   = date('YmdHis') . ".pdf";
        $upload_path = 'filebrief';
        $request->file('filebrief')->move($upload_path, $file_name);
        $data['filebrief']   = $file_name;
      }
    }

    $order->update($data);
    Session::flash('flash_message', 'Data Berhasil Diperbarui.');
    return redirect('admins/order');
}
```

This is code for my form edit:

```
        <div class="form-group">
    <label for="title">Pilih Produk :</label>
    <select name="id_produk" class="form-control" style="width:350px">
        <option value="">- Produk -</option>
        @foreach ($produks as $key => $value)
            <option value="{{ $key }}">{{ $value }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
@if ($errors -> any())
  <div class="form-group {{ $errors -> has('id_item') ? 'has-error' : 'has-success' }}">
    @else
    <div class="form-group">
      @endif
<label for="title">Pilih Item :</label>
<select name="id_item" class="form-control" style="width:350px">
                <option value="">- Item -</option>
</select>
            @if ($errors -> has('id_item'))
  <span class="help-block">{{ $errors -> first('id_item') }}</span>
@endif
```

This is js code for form edit (dropdown) :

```
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('select[name="id_produk"]').on('change', function() {
                        var produkid = $(this).val();
                        if(produkid) {
                            $.ajax({
                                url: 'admins/order/ajax/'+produkid,
                                type: "GET",
                                dataType: "json",
                                success:function(data) {
                                    $('select[name="id_item"]').empty();
                                    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                                        $('select[name="id_item"]').append('<option value="'+ key +'">'+ value +'</option>');
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                        }else{
                            $('select[name="id_item"]').empty();
                        }
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

Why wont work?

Comment: try to console.log(data) is there any value ?

Comment: Nothing, except Navigated to http://localhost:8000/admins/order/23/edit